# PHP confused about use of __DIR__ and ../ in a path

Tags: php, path, filesystems

I came across a project with this structure.

```
-projectRoot
--src
---bootstrap.php
--composer.json
--public
---index.php
---css
---images
```

Now in public directory, `index.php` contains the following

```
//in projectRoot/public/index.php
<?php

  require __DIR__."/../src/bootstrap.php";

 ?>
```

I understand that `__DIR__` constant resolve to absolute directory of the  current executing php script file.So in the above example I would expect it to be `ProjectRoot/public`.

#### the quention

Which path will `require` in index.php look into ? and what does a parent dir `..` in the path above resolve to ?

*PS*: I read that the whole point of the setup above is to ensure relative paths continue to work regardless where index.php is called. How does that work exactly? thanks.

Comment: downvoter can you explain your -1. Considering my reputation level, This is not obvious to me

Comment: Upvoted during review, i dont see any reason for the downvote in the first place, but the post complies with SO guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . "/some_file.php";   
    /* __DIR__ SIMPLY POINTS TO THE DIRECTORY IN WHICH THE ACTIVE SCRIPT LIVES
       - THE DIRECTORY OF THE EXECUTING SCRIPT... THEN REQUIRES THE FILE
       "some_file.php" WITHIN THAT DIRECTORY.
       THE REAL-PATH SHOULD REFLECT SOMETHING LIKE: projectRoot/public/some_file.php
    */

    require __DIR__ . "/../src/bootstrap.php"; 
    /* FOLLOWING THE LOGIC ABOVE, __DIR__ . "/../"  __DIR__ AGAIN POINTS TO 
       THE DIRECTORY IN WHICH THE ACTIVE SCRIPT LIVES WHILE "/../" TELLS
       THE REQUIRE DIRECTIVE TO LOOK ONE DIRECTORY ABOVE THE CURRENT DIRECTORY
       (AND LOCATE WITHIN THAT DIRECTORY ANOTHER DIRECTORY CALLED "src" IN THIS CASE...)
       THEN WITHIN THAT "scr" DIRECTORY LOOK FOR A FILE CALLED:
       "bootstrap.php" AND REQUIRE/INCLUDE IT...
       THE REAL-PATH SHOULD REFLECT SOMETHING LIKE: projectRoot/src/bootstrap.php
    */

     // TO UNDERSTAND THESE CONCEPTS MORE CLEARLY, IT WOULD BE ADVISED TO 
     // TRY SOMETHING LIKE THESE:
     var_dump( realpath(__DIR__ . "/../src/bootstrap.php") );
     var_dump( realpath(__DIR__ . "/index.php") );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening in your `index.php`:

```
__DIR__ // This will be projectRoot/public
/../    // This will go one level up so it'll be projectRoot
src/    // This will go inside the src folder (projectRoot/src)
bootstrap.php // This will open the bootstrap.php
```

So in the end, it's going to target `projectRoot/src/bootstrap.php`... that's the file it's requiring.

Comment: so `../` is resolved in the current path is found in ?

Comment: The `..` is the equivalent of `cd ..` in Linux. Which means it'll go up by one folder wherever the current path is located at. If you had another folder inside public, and you do `../../`, it will go back to `projectRoot`.

Comment: in the context of a php script, where is current path loacted at ?

Comment: Well the located of your php script? For example, your `index.php` is located at `projectRoot/public/index.php`